# Macro to move oldest record to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking through the website and have not found a similar situation yet. Specifically, what I'm looking to do is the following.

Using the table with three columns,

```
Number      Priority Age
1234567890  Low      1
1234567890  Low      2
1234567890  High     3
1234567890  High     4
```

I would like a VBA macro that will first copy the oldest record (determined by the age column), send it over to the current sheet, then delete that record from the main sheet, followed by saving the Excel file.

Again, I have not found anything near this just yet since all the ones I've seen copy ALL rows instead of specifics.

Any help would be amazing!

Edit: Here's the VBA code I tried using but I keep getting the same results (all rows being copied).

`code`

```
Sub MyMacro()
Dim i As Long, iMatches As Long
Dim aTokens() As String: aTokens = Split("10", ",")
For Each cell In Sheets("master").Range("A:A")
    If (Len(cell.Value) = 0) Then Exit For
        For i = 0 To UBound(aTokens)
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, aTokens(i), vbTextCompare) Then
                iMatches = (iMatches + 1)
                Sheets("master").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("top10").Rows(iMatches)
            End If
        Next
Next
End Sub
```

`code`

Comment: why not use `AutoFilter` by "Age" ? and then cut one by one ?

Comment: I am sure something is wrong, as I checked your code is not moving anything. aTokens is always empty! there is no "," in 10? really confusing!

Comment: It'd be fine you either adapt your shown code to your question or the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this just wanted to be runned once, this will work. Not sure why you are using arrays. Your table have 3 columns, but you are saying two! Anyway this is working on your table.

```
Sub Move_Oldest()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim Trow as long
Lrow = Sheets("top10").Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row
With Sheets("master")
    Set Rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(3))
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
         trow = Application.Match(Application.Max(Rng), Rng, 0)
        .Cells(trow, 1).Resize(, 3).Copy Sheets("top10").Cells(Lrow + 1, 1)
        .rows(trow).delete
    End If
End With
End Sub
```